# Hit or Miss Method Question

Tags: probability

I´m working on trying to prove a relation when using the Hit or Miss Method. Suppose we have $g$ bounded in $[0,1]$ and suppose $0 \leq g(X) \leq b$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Let $U1, U2$ be independent random numbers and set
$X = U1$, $Y = bU2$ so the point $(X, Y)$ is uniformly distributed in a rectangle of
length 1 and height $b$. Now set

$$I = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $Y \leq g(X)$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I have to show that $$E[I]=\int_{0}^1g(x)/b$$

I think I can start by saying that $$E[I]=P(Y\lt g(x))$$

but I´m not sure if this is a valid relationship. Can someone explain me why the above is or is not correct?

Thank You!

Comment: Letting $p=P(Y\leq g(X))$ well $I\sim Bernoulli(p)$ where expected value of Bernoulli rv is just $p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have knowledge of conditional expectation. But I think it is desirable to solve correctly this question.
Well, the equality you wrote down $E[I] = P(Y \le g(x))$ should be

$$ E[I] = P(Y \le g(X))$$ note I used the big $X$ (for the random variable). Maybe it was a typo...

Now, you use that $Y = bU_2 $ and $X = U_1$ .. So

$$E[I] = P(bU_2 \le g(U_1)) = P(U_2 \le b^{-1}g(U_1))$$

Now you have to calculate $P(U_2 \le b^{-1}g(U_1))$, but we know compute this probability only if we have a number on the other side of the inequality, agree? But we have another random variable, independent of $U_2$, but it is still a random variable. Then you can use the concept of conditional expectation. Suppose you know the value of $U_1$, so you would be able to compute this probability, right?
So, we condition on $U_1$

$$E[I | U_1] = P(U_2 \le b^{-1}g(U_1)| U_1)$$ but now, we see $U_1$ as number, so
$$E[I | U_1] = P(U_2 \le b^{-1}g(U_1)| U_1) = b^{-1}g(U_1)$$ because $U_1$ has uniform distribution. Now we "sum" over all the possibles values $U_1$ can assume, this sum result in a integration 
$$E[I] = \int_0^1 b^{-1}g(U_1)dP(w)=\int_0^1 b^{-1}g(x)dx$$
by a change of variables and the fact that $U_1$ is uniform on $[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) really clear and easy to understand. I just think we still  need the b^-1 at the end, or am I wrong?

Comment: oh! You right! I edited my answer! =)